# Javascript: If statement not executing despite condition true and code to be executed works outside of If

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to complete an assignment that simulates the micromouse challenge, where I need to map walls and then find the best path to the goal.  I have been building out my blocks to move and to detect collision with a wall and was having success until my screen froze.  I had my code saved and so restarted my laptop and pasted my code back in but now one of my If statements doesn't execute and I can't see what is wrong.  Each function (the in-built isColllisionDetected() and my function offWall()) works separately for the same move input.  But together I now get nothing.
This is my first post here so not sure if you need more information thn the below, please let me know.  Any guidance on what I am missing would be hugely appreciated.
Key points:

1. isCollisionDetected() is an inbuilt function of the environment.  When the robot hits a wall this returns true
2. offWall() is my code, when called the robot moves in reverse for a few pixels and then stops. I have included this code just in case, although it refers to other functions I have not shown here.  I need to use this when I hit a wall so I can move away from the wall and then reorient the robot.
3. When I call the offWall() function on it's own, the code executes correctly.
4. When I deliberately run the robot into a wall and println(isCollisionDetected()), the output is true.
5. My If statement as below does not execute, despite the individual components seemingly working in isolation

**edited to show full code**

full code

```
// function for directional movement
function direction() {
    if ((getHeading() >= 1.47) && (getHeading() <= 1.66)) {
        return "South";
    }
    if ((getHeading() >= 4.62) && (getHeading() <= 4.80)) {
        return "North"; 
    } 
    if ((getHeading() >= 6.19) && (getHeading() <= 0.87)) {
    return "East"; 
    }
    if ((getHeading() >= 3.05) && (getHeading() <= 3.23)) {
    return "West"; 
    }
}

// function for tile coordinates
function tileX() {
    return (Math.floor(getX() / 64));
}
function tileY() {
    return (Math.floor(getY() / 64));
}

// truncate decimal places to 4
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 4,      
   maximumFractionDigits: 4,
});

// calculate diagonal distance
function magnitude(x, y) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
}

// velocity calculation
velocity = magnitude(getVelocityX(), getVelocityY());

// create turn function with degrees conversion
function turn(angleDeg) {
    angleDeg = angleDeg * (formatter.format(Math.PI / 180));
    let delta = 0;
    do {
        delta = angleDeg - getHeading();
        let v = Math.min(1 , Math.abs(delta));
        if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.002) {
             if (delta > 0) {
                setLeftPower(v);
                setRightPower(-v);
            } else {
                setLeftPower(-v);
                setRightPower(v);
            }
        } else {
            setLeftPower(0);
            setRightPower(0);
        }
    } while (Math.abs(delta) > 0.002);
}

// move foreward function with distance in tiles
function forward(distance) {
    clearCollision();
    distance = distance * 64;
    const startX = getX();
    const startY = getY();
    const leeway = 5;
    let travelled = 0;
    let delta = 0;
    let velocity = magnitude(getVelocityX(), getVelocityY());
    do {
        travelled = magnitude(
           getX() - startX, getY() - startY
        );
        delta = distance - travelled;
        if (Math.abs(delta > leeway)) {
            let v = Math.min(1 , Math.abs(delta) / 64);
            if (delta > 0) {
                setLeftPower(v);
                setRightPower(v);
            } else {
                setLeftPower(-v);
                setRightPower(-v);
            }
        } else {
            setLeftPower(0);
            setRightPower(0);           
        }
    } while (
        !isCollisionDetected() && (
            Math.abs(delta) > 3 ||
            Math.abs(velocity) > 3
       )
    );
    setLeftPower(0);
    setRightPower(0);
}

function offWall() {
    const d = 5;
    const startX = getX();
    const startY = getY();
    
    let travelled = 0;
    do {
        travelled = magnitude(
           getX() - startX, getY() - startY
        );
        if (travelled < d) {
        setLeftPower(-0.1);
        setRightPower(-0.1);
        }   
    } while (travelled < d);
    
    setLeftPower(0);
    setRightPower(0);
}


// wall locator functions for Y and X
function wallLocY() {
    if (direction("South")) {
    return (tileY() + 1);
    }
    if (direction("North")) {
    return (tileY() - 1);
    }
}
function wallLocX() {
    if (direction("East")) {
    return (tileX() + 1);
    }
    if (direction("West")) {
    return (tileX() - 1);
    }
}
```

This is all followd by my If statement:

```
if (isCollisionDetected()) {
    println("wall found");    
    offWall();
    setLeftPower(0);
    setRightPower(0);
    clearCollision();
}
```

Which is then followed by me calling a movement function, eg forward(9);

Comment: the problem is, we have no idea WHERE in your code you have `if (isCollisionDetected()) {` ... most likely you have it in a place that gets executed exactly once, on page load, and never gets tested again ... common mistake

Comment: it is the last code block on my page before I call my move functions (eg forward(10)).  I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that I should have it as the last thing?  I have all of my functions coded first, defining direction, speed and maze location.  Collision detection is my last statement.  Should it be elsewhere?

Comment: yeah, so it gets tested once and once only ... you need to test more often than that ... as for "should it be elsewhere", yes ... where? depends on the rest of your code ... check every time something moves

Comment: would it be more appropriate to put it inside a while (true) loop? I have pasted the remainder of my code in case this helps.  And thanks so much!

Comment: no, because the while(true) loop will freeze the rest of your code - and your question hasn't changed - so, not sure where you've pasted the remainder of your code

Comment: ahh ok.  I just edited the original post, apologies

Comment: code like this (game) usually "loops" using `requestAnimationFrame` (if you're doing it right) or `setInterval`/`setTimeout` (if you're doing it the old school way) - somewhere in the code that runs periodically, you test for collisions

Comment: Got it!  Once I changed my movement call to above the If statement it now works!  THANK YOU so I just need to get the order of the If becuase it only runs once, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Just answering this formally, thanks to @Jaromanda X.

I needed to move the If statement to after calling my movement function so it can run at the right time in my code block.  thanks for helping me, I was feeling crazy :)